# storing json data that will be access/altered often in db or in file?

Tags: json, database, file, architecture, data-storage

1. json will be updated up to ~4 times a day
2. json will be loaded often (every user will use this as a base
   data)
3. will need to keep last previous version every saved change
   (one backup copy)

given these cases is there a definite pro/con of storing the json data in a file on the server vs storing it in the database? And if storing it in the database, would it make sense for it to have its own table (two rows, one current version, one backup copy)

Answer (score 1):

Storing, fetching and even querying JSON these days isn't a big deal - especially with the NoSQL solutions like MongoDB & Cassandra.  In fact, a platform like MongoDB will allow you to make direct queries into JSON itself - in fact, it stores it's data as JSON documents and performs quite well.  (I am going to assume you are not talking about massive scale, at least not yet.)

The point being that a system like MongoDB has done a lot of the hard work for you.  It will effectively optimize things for you like loading frequent documents into memory, optimize their sizes and provide mechanisms for traversing large JSON documents without huge footprints.

If you were to deal with this at the file-by-file level, there are going to be a lot of unforeseen issues that you will need to deal with down the road.  You need to manage file handles, watch out for read/write locks on concurrent reads, filesystem permissions, handling disk I/O performance bottlenecks - the list goes on.  Even for webservers these days which serve files day and night, where they have done some pretty interesting optimizations to manage the performance of handling files end up working with CDNs (Content Delivery Networks) to optimize performance at the edge and manage scale.

Retaining prior versions of the JSON data can be as simple as simply not over-writing the existing entry and marking previous previous (n-2) version for deletion.  This can then be done in a separate thread to "clean-up" or a batch process overnight to remove the extraneous data.  (NOTE: this could lead to some fragmentation down the line but it's something that can be compacted later on.)

So, long story short.  I wouldn't store JSON on the filesystem anymore.  Put it in something like MongoDB and let it handle the nitty gritty details.  Until you really get to 1B+ transactions, this should probably do pretty well for you.